# Trouble in using Xcopy to copy to a network path in batch file

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, xcopy

Code:

```
::CopyTest.bat
@ECHO
echo 123>>%temp%\MBDocuments.txt
xcopy "C:\Users\Foo\Documents\" pushd "X:\foo team\Team Members\foo\Documents"
del /q %temp%\MBDocuments.txt
pause
```

So I have another script that pulls this for percentages but it will not execute the above script here is the output.

```
Invalid Number of Parameters
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Is it because I'm pushing to another directory on the network?

I have Privileges across the companies network and access to the drive im backing up to.

At first I thought it was the arguments I was using. But its still Saying Invalid Parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind after some more research I just used `Robocopy` and used the following code which worked.

```
::CopyTest.bat
@ECHO
echo 123>>%temp%\MBDocuments.txt
robocopy C:\Users\foo\Documents\ "X:\foo team\Team Members\foo\Support Desktop" /e /b /xo
del /q %temp%\MBDocuments.txt
pause
```